# Saving Profile Picture and Header Photo to Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have a viewcontroller for a user to edit their profile picture and header photo. I have it to where the user selects a photo and it will save to firebase database and then will download the image and display it in the proper UIImage Views. Only problem I am having is that if I only edit the profile picture and hit save it saves both the profile picture and header photo even though I did not edit header photo. It also saves the data from the profile picture selected for both the profile picture and header photo which erases the original header photo and displaying the selected profile image in both UIImage Views. I'm not sure why it is doing this, I'm sure I am missing something important but I'm not sure what it is. Here is my entire viewcontroller for this.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class NewEditProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameDisplay: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var artistBandDJ: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var editArtistBandDJ: UIButton!


    let you = ["Artist", "Band", "DJ", "Musician", "Producer"]

    var picker:UIPickerView!
    var ref = DatabaseReference.init()

    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var imagePicked = 0

    var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()



    var selectedImage1: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true


        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        self.databaseRef.child("users/profile").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
            let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]
            self.usernameDisplay.text = dict!["username"] as? String
            self.artistBandDJ.text = dict!["What do you consider yourself?"] as? String

            if(dict!["photoURL"] != nil) {

            let databaseProfilePic = dict!["photoURL"] as! String

                if let data = NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: databaseProfilePic)! as URL) {

                    self.setProfilePic(imageView: self.imageView1,imageToSet:UIImage(data: data as Data)!)
                }
            }

            if(dict!["headerURL"] != nil) {
                let databaseHeaderPic = dict!["headerURL"] as! String

                if let data2 = NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string:databaseHeaderPic)! as URL) {

                    self.setHeaderPic(imageView2: self.imageView2, imageToSet2: UIImage(data: data2 as Data)!)

                }
            }


                }
        }


    @IBAction func chooseImage1(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary){
            imagePicked = (sender as AnyObject).tag
            present(imagePicker, animated: true)
        }

        }

    @IBAction func chooseImage2(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary){
            imagePicked = (sender as AnyObject).tag
                present(imagePicker, animated: true)
    }

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage
        let pickedImage2 = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage

        if imagePicked == 1 {
            self.imageView1.image = pickedImage
        } else if imagePicked == 2 {
            self.imageView2.image = pickedImage2
        }
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.saveFIRData()
    self.saveHeaderPhoto()
    self.savePicker()
    self.saveUpdateName()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


    func saveFIRData() {
        guard let image = imageView1.image else { return }

        self.uploadProfileImage(image){ url in


            if url != nil {
                   self.saveProfileImage(profileURL: url!){ success in
                       if success != nil{
                           print("yes")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    func saveHeaderPhoto() {
        guard let image2 = imageView2.image else { return }

        self.uploadHeaderImage(image2){ url in

        self.saveHeaderImage(profileURL2: url!){ success in
            if success != nil {
                print("yes")
                }
            }
        }
    }





    @IBAction func editButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.editButtonTapped()
    }

    func editButtonTapped() {
    let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
        let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150))
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
        vc.view.addSubview(picker)
        let editBandDJAlert = UIAlertController(title: "What do you consider yourself?", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        editBandDJAlert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")
        editBandDJAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: nil))
        editBandDJAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(editBandDJAlert, animated:true)
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return you.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return you[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        artistBandDJ.text = you[row]
    }
    internal func setProfilePic(imageView:UIImageView,imageToSet:UIImage) {
           imageView1.layer.cornerRadius = imageView1.bounds.height / 2
           imageView1.layer.masksToBounds = true
           imageView1.image = imageToSet
       }

       internal func setHeaderPic(imageView2:UIImageView,imageToSet2:UIImage) {
           imageView2.layer.masksToBounds = true
           imageView2.image = imageToSet2
       }

    func savePicker() {

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let selectedValue = artistBandDJ.text

        let ref = Database.database().reference().root

        let userObject = [
            "What do you consider yourself?":selectedValue
        ]
        ref.child("users/profile").child(uid).updateChildValues(userObject as [AnyHashable : Any])
    }

    func saveUpdateName() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        let updatedName = usernameDisplay.text

        let ref = Database.database().reference().root

        let userObject = [
            "username":updatedName
        ]

        ref.child("users/profile").child(uid).updateChildValues(userObject as [AnyHashable : Any])

    }

}

extension NewEditProfileViewController {


    func uploadProfileImage(_ image:UIImage, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL?)->()) {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("users/\(uid)")
        let imageData = imageView1.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)
        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        storageRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: metaData) { (metaData, error) in
            if error == nil{
                print("success for profile photo")
                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    completion(url)
                })
            }else{
                print("error in save image")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func uploadHeaderImage(_ image2:UIImage, completion: @escaping (_ url2: URL?)->()) {
          guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
          let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("users/\(uid)")
          let imageData2 = imageView2.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)
          let metaData = StorageMetadata()
          metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"
          storageRef.putData(imageData2!, metadata: metaData) { (metaData, error) in
              if error == nil{
                  print("success for header")
                  storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                      completion(url)
                  })
              }else{
                  print("error in save image")
                  completion(nil)
              }
          }
      }


    func saveProfileImage(profileURL:URL, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?) -> ())){
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/profile/\(uid)")
        let userObject = [
            "photoURL": profileURL.absoluteString
        ] as [String:Any]
        self.ref.child("users/profile").child(uid).updateChildValues(userObject)
        }

    func saveHeaderImage(profileURL2:URL, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?) -> ())){
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/profile/\(uid)")
    let userObject = [
        "headerURL": profileURL2.absoluteString
    ] as [String:Any]
    self.ref.child("users/profile").child(uid).updateChildValues(userObject)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're overriding everything when the users presses the save button. This could be solved by adding a property `var headerChanged = false` to the view controller. Then in `chooseImage1` you set it to true.

When `saveButton` is called you check whether it has changed or not by checking the flag (`headerChanged`).